# How to sort command name + arguments output of ps in solaris

Tags: solaris, sort, ps, arguments, command-names

Below is my sample output of `ps` command in solaris

```
myuser  26856  0.0  0.1 1716368 118576 ?        S   Feb 18  2:17 /web/bea/platform1221/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/web/bea/platform1221/wlserver/common/derby/derbyServer.policy -Dderby.system.home=/web/bea_apps/domains/common/db -classpath /web/bea/platform1221/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derby.jar:/web/bea/platform1221/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/web/bea/platform1221/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbytools.jar:/web/bea/platform1221/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar:/web/bea/platform1221/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start
myuser    934  0.0  0.0 11112 9064 ?        S   Jan 28  0:10 /web/bea_apps/apache/2.4.37/httpd-prod.viewlogs/bin/httpd -k start
root      1621  0.0  0.0    0    0 ?        S   Jan 24  0:00 zsched
myuser   2140  0.0  0.0 14368 10152 ?        S   Feb 07  0:00 /bin/sh /web/bea_apps/domains/bin/startWebLogic.sh
root      2369  0.0  0.0 15624 11168 ?        S 21:15:17  0:00 /usr/share/centrifydc/sbin/sshd -R
myuser   2372  0.0  0.0 6016 4752 pts/24   S 21:15:17  0:00 -ksh
```

I tried `-o` but then it does not print arguments

I wish to sort on whatever is left after discarding the below ahead of the actual command.

Discard the below for each process before sorting on the rest

`root      1621  0.0  0.0    0    0 ?        S   Jan 24  0:00`

I'm on : `$ uname -a SunOS myhost 5.11 11.4.28.82.3 sun4v sparc sun4v`

Here is the solaris `ps` man page: https://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/ps/

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Did you try `ps -o comm,args`?

Comment: The first code block shows seven columns, the second eleven. You could pipe the output to `sort -k7` or `sort -k 11`.

Comment: That man page is from 2008 - the current Solaris 11.4 man page for ps is at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/ps-1.html